# iOS5 with storyboards, where to put common app objects init code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, storyboard

Before I was using storyboards, all of my controllers were initialized in:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

I could init all the common objects (data managers, etc) before creating controllers, and pass them to controllers.

In my first storyboard project, I noticed that one of my controllers has its

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
//called before the app's 
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

**If I"m using storyboards and my controllers get loaded before the app finishes launching, where should I put my common objects init code to ensure that it gets called only once?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From the docs for application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

> ...It is called after your application has been launched and its main
>   nib file has been loaded.

To prevent loading your storyboard before your initialization you can remove your main xib file or storyboard in the -Info.plist (for storyboard it is called `Main storyboard file base name`). Then you can create your storyboard manually when you need that.

Comment: Storyboards are completely new to me, I don't know how to create them manually :/

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIStoryboard/storyboardWithName:bundle: